# Showing that Banach spaces are complete, separable, and perfect.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I'm working on a proof right now, but I seem to be stuck. How would I show that

$l_q := \{ x = (x_i)_i \in \mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}/\|x\|_q := (\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}|x_i|^q)^{1/q}  < \infty \}$

and

$c_o := \{ x = (x_i)_i \in \mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}/ \lim\limits_{i}x_i = 0, \|x\|_\infty := \sup\limits_{i}|x_i| \}$

are complete, separable, and perfect?

Comment: That's a lot of stuff ! Here are a few directions you could look in. _1) Completeness_ : Take an arbitrary Cauchy sequence (which will be a Cauchy sequence of sequences) in the given space and show that it **converges in the given space** and that **the limit is in the given space**. This requires a bit of technical work but is very straightforward. _2) Separability_: Consider the space of sequences in $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ of the form $(u_1,u_2,...,u_n,0,0,0,...)$ You should find something interesting.

Comment: _3) Perfectness_: These spaces are closed because they are complete. To show that there are no isolated points take an arbitrary sequence,and build an open ball around it. Does this ball contain only one element ? (It shouldn't !)

Comment: Okay so I was able to show that for $X = l_q$ or $c_0$ that every Cauchy sequence converges, but I'm not sure how to show that it they converge to a point in $X$.

I was able to show separability too. Does perfectness have to do with the fact that we can find Cauchy sequence that converges to any point in $X$? Thanks.

Comment: For separability consider the set of $(x_i)_i$ such that $Re(x_i)$ and $Im(x_i)$ are rational for every $i,$ and such that $x_i=0$ for all but finitely many $i.$

Comment: For perfectness (perfection?); If $x\ne 0$ then any nbhd $U$ of $x$ covers $\{x(1+r/\|x\|): r\in (0,s)\}$ for some $s>0.$ ... For $x=0$, take $x'\ne 0$. Any nbhd $U$ of $0$ covers $\{x'r/\|x'\|:r\in (0,s)\}$ for some $s>0.$

Comment: @Mandelbob The $\ell_p$-norm triangle inequality will be your good friend. Also rewriting some stuff in the form $|a|=|a+b-b|$ should help. Regarding perfectness if you can prove your claim then yes, the space will be perfect.